# Undefined method 'session' using Sinatra for Facebook Canvas Application

Tags: session, sinatra, rack

I am using sessions in my Facebook Canvas Application using Sinatra and Rack.

The error that occurs in Facebook Canvas is:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `session' for #<Hash:0xa3ed0a0>:
    /home/apoorv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:170:in `session'
```

The problem is surely with Rack because when I run my application as follows:

> ruby application.rb -p 3000

it does not display any error. I have tried installing rack version: 1.3.6 and 1.4.1, but the error persists.

I have also tried using the following code instead of `enable :sessions`

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                           :domain => 'static.ak.facebook.com',
                           :path => '/',
                           :secret => 'change_me'
```

Do I need to upgrade/degrade to lower version of Rack or add some piece of Code to make this thing work?

**edited**

Also before coming across this issue I had an issue integrating my application in Facebook Canvas which was resolved by adding this line in config.ru:

```
set :protection, :except => [:remote_token, :frame_options]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `env['rack.session']` instead of `session[]` in the POST request recieved from Facebook solved this issue. Hope this helps to solve such problems

Though it has **not fully** resolved complications because, now adding a `redirect to` code in the same POST callback displays: `undefined method secure?` error.

I have not been able to solve this issue, though what I did was to avoid the redirect thing and instead add a functionality to the controller to handle different requests.